# Python MySQLdb test for select count(*) = zero

Tags: python, mysql-python

I use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db WHERE <expression>` to see if a set of records is null. So:

```
>>> cnt = c.fetchone()
>>> print cnt
(0L,)
```

My question is: how do you test for this condition?

I have a number of other ways to accomplish this. Is something like the following possible?

```
if cnt==(0L,): 
    # do something
```

Answer (score 2):

`fetchone` returns a row, which is a sequence of columns.

If you want to get the first value in a sequence, you use `[0]`.

You *could* instead compare the row to `(0,)`, as you're suggesting. But as far as I know neither the general DB-API nor the specific MySQLdb library guarantee what *kind* of sequence a row is; it could be a list, or a custom sequence class. So, relying on the fact that it's a tuple is probably not a good idea. And, since it's just as easy to *not* do so, why not be safe and portable?

So:

```
count_row = c.fetchone()
count = count_row[0]
if count == 0:
    do_something()
```

Or, putting it together in one line:

```
if c.fetchone()[0] == 0:
    do_something()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. Your first sequence works, don't know how I did not try that one, but I did not. The second construction gets an error: ...object has no attribute '**getitem**'. I would guess my version of MySQLdb (1.2.3_4, Python 2.7) does not support it.

What I did in the interim was to construct the zero tuple by executing a count(*) constructed to return zero records. This seems to work fine

Answer (score 0):

It's often easier to use the `.rowcount` attribute of the cursor object to check whether there are any rows in your result set. This attribute is [specified in the Python Database API](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#rowcount):

> This read-only attribute specifies the number of rows that the last
>   [.execute*()](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id14) produced (for DQL statements like `SELECT`) or
>   affected (for DML statements like `UPDATE` or `INSERT`). [[9]](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id48)
>
> The attribute is -1 in case no [.execute*()](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id14) has been performed on
>   the cursor or the rowcount of the last operation is cannot be
>   determined by the interface. [[7]](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id46)

### When `.rowcount` cannot be used

Note that per the above specs, `Cursor.rowcount` should be set to `-1` when the number of rows produced or affected by the last statement "cannot be determined by the interface." This happens when using the `SSCursor` and `SSDictCursor` cursor classes.

The reason is that the MySQL C API has two different functions for retrieving result sets: [`mysql_store_result()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-store-result.html) and [`mysql_use_result()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-use-result.html). The difference is that `mysql_use_result()` reads rows from the result set as you ask for them, rather than storing the entire result set as soon as the query is executed. For very large result sets, this "unbuffered" approach can be faster and uses much less memory on the client machine; however, it makes it impossible for the interface to determine how many rows the result set contains at the time the query is executed.

Both `SSCursor` and `SSDictCursor` call `mysql_use_result()`, so their `.rowcount` attribute should hold the value `-1` regardless of the size of the result set. In contrast, `DictCursor` and the default `Cursor` class call `mysql_store_result()`, which reads and counts the entire result set immediately after executing the query.

To make matters worse, the `.rowcount` attribute only ever holds the value `-1` when the cursor is first opened; once you execute a query, it receives the return value of [`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-affected-rows.html). The problem is that `mysql_affected_rows()` returns an unsigned long long integer, which represents the value `-1` in a way that [can be very counterintuitive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9098275/2359271) and wouldn't be caught by a condition like `cursor.rowcount == -1`.

### Counting for counting's sake

If the *only* thing you're doing is counting records, then `.rowcount` isn't that useful because your `COUNT(*)` query is going to return a row whether the records exist or not. In that case, test for the zero value *in the same way that you would test for any value* when fetching results from a query. Whether you can do `c.fetchone()[0] == 0` depends on the cursor class you're using; it would work for a `Cursor` or `SSCursor` but fail for a `DictCursor` or `SSDictCursor`, which fetch dictionaries instead of tuples.

The important thing is just to be clear in your code about what's happening, which is why I would recommend against using `c.fetchone() == (0,)`. That tests *an entire row* when all you need to do is test a single value; get the value out of the row before you test it, and your code will be more clear. Personally, I find `c.fetchone()[0]` to be needlessly opaque; I would prefer:

```
row = cursor.fetchone()
if row[0] == 0:
    do_something()
```

This makes it abundantly clear, without being *too* verbose, that you're testing *the first item of the row*. When I'm doing anything more complicated than a simple `COUNT()` or `EXISTS()`, I prefer to use `DictCursor` so that my code relies on (at most) explicit aliases and never on implicit column ordering.

### Testing for an empty result set

On the other hand, if you actually need to fetch a result set and the counting is purely incidental, as long as you're not using one of the unbuffered cursor classes you can just execute the important query and not worry about the `COUNT()`:

```
cursor.execute(r"SELECT id, name, email FROM user WHERE date_verified IS NULL;")
if cursor.rowcount == 0:
    print 'No results'
```